# Banner responsive on xs devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got banner 750x100 above the navbar. When I minimize window to col-xs, I got two problems -

1) Navbar-brand skip under the line. (Red line)

2) Banner is too small, I want align it to center or enlarge the height. (Blue line)

[image: col-xs]

```
    <div class="container-fluid banner text-center">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/750x100" alt="" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                </a>
            </div>  
    </div>
</div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some long texthere</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

It's possible to arrange place as I wrote, or should I try other way?

Comment: put your code into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18846/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18847/